# Uniqueidentifier value insert dynamic in sql execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to insert value dynamically in `Exec` call in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'tblTestInsert'
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '3781EF06-6EE4-41ED-81C5-9AE7AD4C4356'

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName)
BEGIN
    SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + '(Id, FirstName, LastName, Description) VALUES ('+ CAST(@Id AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) + ',"visual","studio","visual studio 2017")';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Table is not exists';
END
```

But it throws the below error:

> The data types nvarchar(max) and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator.

Please help with this query. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably you meant to use `CAST(@Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning error throw like  Incorrect syntax near 'F06' after use CAST(@Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

Comment: @debugger make sure to enclose the literal value with single quotes.

Comment: @EzLo i'm tried query (based on your query)  like  SET SQLString = 'INSERT INTO ' + tableName + ' (Id,FirstName,LastName,Description)VALUES(CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Id) + '),"visual","studio","visual studio 2017")';

error throw Incorrect syntax near 'F06'.

Comment: @EzLo and AlwaysLearning thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than build the SQL statement with a literal string, use a parameterized query like below. Also, it would be best to use ISO SQL standard single quotes so that the query will run regardless of the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` session setting. Using double-quotes requires `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` and is incompatible with SQL Server features line indexed views, filtered indexes, et. al.

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'tblTestInsert'
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '3781EF06-6EE4-41ED-81C5-9AE7AD4C4356'

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName)
BEGIN
    SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '(Id, FirstName, LastName, Description) VALUES (@Id,''visual'',''studio'',''visual studio 2017'');';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString, N'@Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER', @Id = @Id;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Table does not exist';
END;
```

Comment: above code is working fine. Thanks for your support. 
I have one more doubt. if one or more unique identifier column using in this query, how can i insert the value. Can you please help this doubt?

Comment: @debugger, you can simply specify additional parameters with different names. For example, `SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '(Id, FirstName, LastName, Description, Guid) VALUES (@Id,''visual'',''studio'',''visual studio 2017'', @Guid);';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString, N'@Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER', @Id = @Id, @Guid = @Guid;`

Answer (score 2):

You can't concatenate `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` with `NVARCAHR` without a conversion.

```
DECLARE @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '3781EF06-6EE4-41ED-81C5-9AE7AD4C4356'

SELECT
    N'This is the ID: ' + @Id
```

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 4    The data types nvarchar and
>   uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator.

You want to "rewrite" your unique identifier as a nvarchar so the dynamic SQL correctly interprets it back. Remember that unique identifier isn't text like nvarchar, it's a bunch of 16 bytes.

```
DECLARE @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '3781EF06-6EE4-41ED-81C5-9AE7AD4C4356'

SELECT
    N'This is the ID: ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @Id)
```

Actually I'd explicitly cast to UID on the dynamic part:

```
SET @SQLString = N'
    INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + N' (
        Id, 
        FirstName, 
        LastName, 
        Description) 
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @Id) + N'''),
        ''visual'',
        ''studio''
        ''visual studio 2017''';
```